# PHP parse response from web service that contains the xsd too

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap, schema

I need to parse some xml using PHP SoapClient. 
The response appears to contain the xsd too. 
Below is an example of the response I get.
I welcome your comments and contributions. Thank you very much.

```
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="PRV_Servicios" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="PRV_Servicios">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="idPRV_Servicios" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="Servicios" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="Filler" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="MarkupAvizo" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="MarkUpRest" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="MarkUp" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="IVA" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="idPRV_ServiciosIVA" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="idEMP_Monedas" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="TipoCalculo1" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="TipoCalculo2" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <DocumentElement xmlns="">
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
            <idPRV_Servicios>1</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Aereo</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>0</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>0</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>0</MarkUp>
            <IVA>1</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>1</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>1</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>1</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
            <idPRV_Servicios>2</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Autos</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>8.38</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>1</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>10</MarkUp>
            <IVA>1</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>1</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>1</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>1</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
            <idPRV_Servicios>3</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Cruceros</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>12.5</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>5.5</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>15</MarkUp>
            <IVA>1</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>1</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>1</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>1</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
            <idPRV_Servicios>4</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Excursiones</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>0</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>0</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>0</MarkUp>
            <IVA>0</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>2</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>0</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>0</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
            <idPRV_Servicios>5</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Hoteles</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>12.5</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>5.5</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>15</MarkUp>
            <IVA>0</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>2</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>1</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>2</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios6" msdata:rowOrder="5">
            <idPRV_Servicios>6</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Otros</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>12.5</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>5.5</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>15</MarkUp>
            <IVA>0</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>2</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>2</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>2</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios7" msdata:rowOrder="6">
            <idPRV_Servicios>7</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Trenes</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>15.5</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>5.5</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>22</MarkUp>
            <IVA>1</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>1</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>1</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>1</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios8" msdata:rowOrder="7">
            <idPRV_Servicios>8</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Buses</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>15.5</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>10</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>21</MarkUp>
            <IVA>2</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>1</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>1</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>1</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios9" msdata:rowOrder="8">
            <idPRV_Servicios>9</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Global</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>0</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>0</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>0</MarkUp>
            <IVA>1</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>1</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>1</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>1</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios10" msdata:rowOrder="9">
            <idPRV_Servicios>10</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Traslados</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>12.5</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>5.5</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>15</MarkUp>
            <IVA>0</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>2</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>0</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>0</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios11" msdata:rowOrder="10">
            <idPRV_Servicios>11</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Cena Show</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>0</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>0</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>0</MarkUp>
            <IVA>1</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>1</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>0</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>0</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios12" msdata:rowOrder="11">
            <idPRV_Servicios>12</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Paquetes</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>0</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>0</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>0</MarkUp>
            <IVA>1</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>2</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>0</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>0</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios13" msdata:rowOrder="12">
            <idPRV_Servicios>13</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Asistencia</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>0</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>0</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>0</MarkUp>
            <IVA>1</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>1</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>1</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>1</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios14" msdata:rowOrder="13">
            <idPRV_Servicios>14</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Guia</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>0</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>0</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>0</MarkUp>
            <IVA>1</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>1</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>1</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>1</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
        <PRV_Servicios diffgr:id="PRV_Servicios15" msdata:rowOrder="14">
            <idPRV_Servicios>15</idPRV_Servicios>
            <Servicios>Extras</Servicios>
            <Filler/>
            <MarkupAvizo>0</MarkupAvizo>
            <MarkUpRest>0</MarkUpRest>
            <MarkUp>0</MarkUp>
            <IVA>0</IVA>
            <idPRV_ServiciosIVA>0</idPRV_ServiciosIVA>
            <idEMP_Monedas>2</idEMP_Monedas>
            <TipoCalculo1>0</TipoCalculo1>
            <TipoCalculo2>0</TipoCalculo2>
        </PRV_Servicios>
    </DocumentElement>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us some code.

Comment: This is the code that returns me the XS: SHEMA. thank you very much
`<?php      
$wsdl = "http://192.168.0.1/Service.asmx?WSDL";
//Credenciales
$credenciales = array(); //parametros de la llamada
$credenciales["Usuario"] = "user";
$credenciales["Password"] = "12345";
//Fin de Credenciales
$respuesta = new SoapClient($wsdl);        
$consulta = $respuesta->Consulta_Servicios($credenciales);        
echo "<B>RESPUESTA DE LACONSULTA</B><br>";  
echo "<pre>";
print_r($consulta);
echo "</pre>";              
?>`

Comment: That is not what I asked. I asked if you have written any code that tries to read the xml. You can't just ask for the solution. You have to show some effort.

Comment: Never wrote, Might recomentarme some php code that can read the XML?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: No how to implement the query, because PHP returns me an xs ARRAY: schema, the query as to would have to do it? I translate by google'm from Argentina. Thank you

Comment: Please post the wsdl.

Comment: WSDL: http://agencias.latin-adventure.com/wsmacropax/Service.asmx

Comment: Please post the result of this `print_r($consulta);`

Comment: <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        stdClass Object
(
    [Consulta_ServiciosResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [any] => code posted above
        )

)
    </body>
</html>

Comment: Please make an edit to your post, and paste exactly the result from `print_r($consulta);`

Comment: Check my answer. If this solves your problem, don't forget to mark it.

Comment: Excellent solution to this problem, for weeks I was trying to figure this out. Appreciate

Comment: No problem. Be well and have fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$wsdl = "http://192.168.0.120/Service.asmx?WSDL";

//Credenciales
$credenciales = array(); //parametros de la llamada
$credenciales["Usuario"] = "username";
$credenciales["Password"] = "pass";
//Fin de Credenciales

$respuesta = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$consulta = $respuesta->Consulta_Servicios($credenciales);

$pattern = '/<xs:schema.*<\/xs:schema>/';
$xml = preg_replace($pattern, '', $consulta->Consulta_ServiciosResult->any);

$response = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($response->DocumentElement->PRV_Servicios as $servicio) {
    echo '----------------------------<br>';
    echo 'idPRV_Servicios = ' . $servicio->idPRV_Servicios . '<br>';
    echo 'Servicios = ' . $servicio->Servicios . '<br>';
    echo 'Filler = ' . $servicio->Filler . '<br>';
    echo 'MarkupAvizo = ' . $servicio->MarkupAvizo . '<br>';
    echo 'MarkUpRest = ' . $servicio->MarkUpRest . '<br>';
    echo 'MarkUp = ' . $servicio->MarkUp . '<br>';
    echo 'IVA = ' . $servicio->IVA . '<br>';
    echo 'idPRV_ServiciosIVA = ' . $servicio->idPRV_ServiciosIVA . '<br>';
    echo 'idEMP_Monedas = ' . $servicio->idEMP_Monedas . '<br>';
    echo 'TipoCalculo1 = ' . $servicio->TipoCalculo1 . '<br>';
    echo 'TipoCalculo2 = ' . $servicio->TipoCalculo2 . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks alkin after 5 to 6 hour workout i got your answer & it's solve my issue in just 5 min. also thanks juan Fede for put this question here.